# Finish() method of BaseLoaderCallback does not exist?

Tags: android, opencv, service

I'm currently trying to make the `BaseLoaderCallback` in `OpenCV` to run as a service in an Android application. On `OpenCV website`, there is a information about how to implement the `BaseLoaderCallback` in a service and that is to override the `finish()` method of the `BaseLoaderCallback`. Check out this link: (http://docs.opencv.org/platforms/android/service/doc/BaseLoaderCallback.html)

My issue is that I cannot find the finish method in `BaseLoaderCallback class` (or it does not exist one!?)

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
((Activity)context).finish();
```

use this code